# how to change Ionic native ibeacon's scan interval time?

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, ibeacon, ionic-native

I’m using ionic ibeacon native library to scan beacons.I want to change the beacon scan interval time ,is it possible? I want to send some data to my webservice in didRangeBeaconsInRegion event ,but its kinda calling this 1 sec interval .
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ibeacon/

Any help is appreciated ,thanks

Comment: The underlying iOS Core Location APIs do not let you change this interval, which is fixed at 1 second.  Equivalent Android APIs do allow this, but they may not be exposed through ionic.

Comment: hmm I see ,thanks for you comment.Do you know that 1 secs interval is accurate , i mean if I count 60 times,it will be around 60seconds

Comment: Yes, it is pretty accurate on iOS. On Android using the underlying Android Beacon Library, the callbacks actually come every 1.1 seconds (there are technical reasons for this to accommodate some Android models, but it is similarly accurate), so if you want to do multiply, it has to be platform-specific.